# Trying to show extra information in a responsive DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I just started using DataTables and I am trying to show extra information (retrieved through AJAX) within a Responsive DataTable.

Extra information example - [Link 1](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

Responsive table example - [Link 2](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/ajax.html)

That means, on a big screen, the table will show some 'extra information' about each row on expanding.
On a small screen, I want the table to show the extra information, as well as the rows hidden for responsive purpose.

However, this is not happening.

- In large view, DataTable only shows the extra information on expanding a row. This is as expected.
- But on a smaller screen, it shows ONLY the rows which it hides and the extra information which was shown before, is completely gone.

Is there any way where I can get the Hidden columns AND some Extra information to show when the row is expanded?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

```js
function format ( d ) {
    
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "./data/arrays.txt",
        responsive: true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" class="display stripe compact row-border no-wrap" width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Expand</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [custom child row renderer](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html) with Responsive extension to produce custom content for your rows.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "responsive": {
        "details": {
            "renderer": function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                // Show hidden columns in row details
                var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                    return col.hidden 
                       ? '<tr><td>'+col.title+':</td> '+
                         '<td>'+col.data+'</td></tr>' 
                       : '';
                 } ).join('');

                // Extra: Show "Name" in row details
                data += '<tr><td>Name:</td><td>' + api.cell(rowIdx, 0).data() + '</td></tr>';
                // Generate a table
                data = $('<table width="100%"/>').append( data ).prop('outerHTML');

                // Extra: Show custom content
                data += '<div class="content-custom">Custom content</div>';

                return data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fLwej4u/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely is one of the things I need.

However, in the fiddle, can I get the row to expand and show 'custom-content' even when all the columns (till column 'Extra 10') are visible?

Comment: @RahulMk, That's a good question. See https://jsfiddle.net/3fLwej4u/1/, there could be extra blank column with special class `none`. I'm not sure yet whether this is the most effective way.

Comment: Brilliant!! This is exactly what I need. I see your solutions on many posts; I somehow knew I'd get mine from Gyrocode. Really apreciate your help.

Thank you!